# How do you determine the general geographic location of an incoming HTTP request?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, geolocation

I am using ASP.NET MVC to develop a web application and would like to display different web pages based on the geographic location of the incoming HTTP requests. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are products and services available for this purpose, including but not limited to:

http://www.fraudlabs.com/ip2location.aspx
http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php
http://www.ip2location.com/
http://www.iplocationtools.com
http://www.smart-ip.net/en/api/